# Update related object with rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Given the following models:-

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField()
    etc.

class Relation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='relations', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_primary = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

how would I go about creating a serializer and view that can be used to set a particular user's relation to be the primary one?

I was hoping to be able to POST something like:-

```
{ 'relation': 6 }
```

and for that to find the Relation with ID of 6 and set it's is_primary to True but I can't figure out how to do it.

I've tried the serializer like this:-

```
class SetRelationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    relation = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Relation.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['relation']
```

and a viewset action like this:-

```
@action(['post'], detail=False)
def set_primary_relation(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    // what do I need in here?

    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Is the only way to do something like:-

```
self.request.user.relations.get(id=serializer.data['relation']).update(is_primary=True)
```

? Because that seems a bit unpleasant to me.

Surely there's a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can override the update method of serializer.

```
class SetRelationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     ...

      def update(self, instance, validated_data):
               relation = validated_data.get("relation")
               relation.set_primary = True
               relation.save()
               return {}
```